# How do I build variable-names dynamically?

Tags: php, html, smarty

In my web-application I use egotech4 with Smartry-Script in html.

I have some variables named e.g.

```
{$page->extra.name878}
```

but I need to get their values without know the number at the end, this number I can get from an other variable `{$item->field.id}`

so I tried something like:

```
{assign var=name value="extra.name`$item->field.id`"}
 <h4>{$page->$name}</h4>
```

But it doesn't work, it seems not to find the value of the property `extra.nameXYZ` of the `$page` variable. 
Sadly I can not use any php-code for this I need to get it working with SMARTY only.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why can't you use arrays instead of dynamic variable names?

Comment: The problem is, that the value of $page->extra... is stored in a database of the egotech-system by an other site. <br /> So it makes no difference between Array and dynamically variable-name, cause there is no way around reading a part of the variable-name out of an other variable.

Edit2: just tried it, saving as array doesn't work probably :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Problem:

use:

```
{assign var=name value="name`$item->field.id`"}
```

instad of:

```
{assign var=name value="extra.name`$item->field.id`"}
```

and read it out with:

```
{$page->extra.$name}
```

Many thanks goes to Dan Günther from EGOTECH-Support who gave me that hint.